# Composer does not pull the package for v10.4.21

Tags: composer-php, typo3-10.x

I want to update to TYPO3 version 10.4.21 but only get 10.4.20 via composer update. What could be the reason?
This is my composer file:

```
 "require": {
    "typo3/cms-adminpanel": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-backend": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-belog": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-beuser": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-core": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-extbase": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-extensionmanager": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-felogin": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-filelist": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-filemetadata": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-fluid": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-form": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-frontend": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-impexp": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-indexed-search": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-info": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-install": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-linkvalidator": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-lowlevel": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-recordlist": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-recycler": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-redirects": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-reports": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-scheduler": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-seo": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-setup": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^10.4.21",
    "typo3/cms-workspaces": "^10.4.21"
  }
 "conflict": {
    "psr/cache": "2.0.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.11.2"
  },
```

I tried it also with "10.4.21" and "v10.4.21" and "^10.4".

Comment: What happens when you run `composer update` or anything else?

Comment: It will only be updated to 10.4.20. And if I explicitly state the version, it hangs without a timeout or error

Comment: What does `composer why-not typo3/cms-core 10.4.21` return?

Comment: Thank you very much for this command. It shows me that dependencies in an extension are wrong. I used the extension m1 / vars in my base and this again depends on symfony / filesystem (^ 2.8 | ^ 3.0). But TYPO3 10.4.21 needs symfony / filesystem (^ 4.4 || ^ 5.0). I will now adjust m1 / vars or look for a replacement. Thank you again :)